# Python - Create a recursion function

Tags: python-3.x

my question is basically this: Create a recursion function that takes a nested list as a 
parameter and returns the sub-list that has minimum difference between its maximum and minimum elements.

For example: Function should return [1,2] for input [[1,199,59],[1,2],[3,8]]

I searched Google and stackoverflow, but i could not find this specific example.

What i would like to get help is with iteration. I want to, using recursion, iterate over each sub-list(can be as many as possible). I have achieved this with a for loop, but i cannot grasp the idea of iteration by using recursion method.

So far, i have this:

```
def sublist(mylist):
    if len(mylist) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(mylist) == 1:
        return mylist
    else:
        a = (mylist[0][0]) - (mylist[0][-1])
        if a < sublist(mylist[1:]):
            return mylist[0]
sublist([[1,199,58],[1,2],[3,8]])
```

This part, ( sublist(mylist[1:]) ) i know is clearly wrong. I'm trying to compare the value a, with the values from the mylist[1:]. I would appreciate much advice here.

Updated:

```
def differences(mylist):

    diff = max(mylist) - min(mylist)

    return diff


def sublist(nestedlist):

    if len(nestedlist) == 1:

        return nestedlist[0]

    else:

        if differences(nestedlist[0]) < differences(sublist(nestedlist[1:])):

            return nestedlist[0]

        else:

            return sublist(nestedlist[1:])


print(sublist([[1,199,59],[1,2],[3,8]]))
```

Comment: `"I searched Google and stackoverflow, but i could not find this specific example."` Wait... So you might have to *actually* **write** code, instead of stitching together examples from the Internet?! People *do* that?

Comment: Why do you wanna do it recursively if you can do it iteratively? Maybe elaborate a little bit more? Or show some code?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes i have to write a code and this is what i have so far, by my own:   def sublist(mylist):
    if len(mylist) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(mylist) == 1:
        return mylist
    else:
        a = (mylist[0][0]) - (mylist[0][-1])
        if a < sublist(mylist[1:]):
            return a
sublist([[1,199,58],[1,2],[3,8]])
my logic is to compare the value of a with the values i get from the other nested-list and then return it. But it's clearly very wrong, any Advice.

Comment: This comment section is very confusing, for i can't seem to write an organized code

Comment: Edit it in to your question, instead of leaving it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am assuming that you want to use recursion for the first level of the list. So, without giving you the code 100%, you have to do something like that:

1) create a method e.g `diferences(list)` that calculates the differences of a list and returns a list with the parameter list and the min difference i.e `differences([1,2])` should return `[1, [1,2]]`. call it once on the first sublist i.e `min = differences(mylist[0])`

2) create your sublist method like this:

```
def sublist(initial_list):

   # 1) call differences() method for the first sublist of the 'initial_list'
   # 2) update 'min'  with differences(initial_list[0])if differences(inilitial_list[0])[0] < min[0]; 
   # 3) call sublist() again now removing the sublist you checked before from the arguement
   # 4) (the following should be at the start of your sublist() method) 

   if len(initial_list) = 1:
       if differences(initial_list) < min: 
            return initial_list
       else: return min[1]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i finally got. And sorry for replying very late. I have edited my final answer in the question.

Comment: Feel free to vote up/accept if this helped you then :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, "Vote up requires 15 reputation".